# Also show search results when search string comes close to item names

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, search

I am making a website, with several products. This webshop sells boat trips. I have a few items with the name 'daytrip'. But when I search for 'daytrips', I get no search results at all.

I would like to get results for 'daytrip', when I am looking for 'daytrips'. How to I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by assigning a synonym to the `daytrips` search keyword.
Go to `Catalog->Search terms`.
Look for the search term `daytrips` (if it does not exist, add it), edit it and in the field `Synonym For` fill in `daytrip`.